# Calculate mean of each subsequent group of 2 rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, mean

I'm trying to calculate the mean of each subsequent group of 2 rows for all data frame. I think I got that with the following line:
`df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2).mean()`

However, the problem is that not all values are numeric. In that case, if the second line of the group is numeric while the first is not, instead of the mean, the value stays the same as the second row. In case of both lines be non numeric, the value should be assigned with 0.

For a better visualization, I have this dataframe:

```
    Well    Ct
0    A1    Undetermined
1    A2    Undertermined
2    A3    Undetermined
3    A4    41.2
4    B1    42
5    B2    43
```

What I'm trying to obtain is:

```
     Well     Ct
0    A1-A2    0.0
1    A3-A4    41.2
2    B1/B2    42.5
```

Is there any way to do this or other similar question that was already been posted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pandas.to_numeric` to coerce non-numeric values to `NaN`s (which pandas will ignore by default when calculating means), then use `groupby` + `agg` to assign your final groups.

---

```
df.Ct = pd.to_numeric(df.Ct, errors='coerce')

df.groupby(np.arange(df.shape[0]) // 2).agg({'Well': '-'.join, 'Ct': 'mean'}).fillna(0)
```

```
    Well    Ct
0  A1-A2   0.0
1  A3-A4  41.2
2  B1-B2  42.5
```

Comment: Worked just fine! Thank you!